# facebook apprequest dialog onclick request open other url

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

## My Code is like ::

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"hi test",  @"message", @"Check this out", @"notification_text", self.objFriendBean.FBUserId, @"to", nil];

[appDelegate.fbGraph dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params CallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(isSendNotificatonToFriend:)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same problem .Instead of request you should use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/ share dialog with which you can send the web content to the feeds of your friend.

Comment: no i have send the apprequest not shar my feed. your solution for share feed. but i have problem in send apprequest